# Accent encodings

Tags: delphi, unicode, utf-16

I try to read a string containing accents in Delphi.
I don t know the real encoding of he string. 
I suppose it is UNICODE.

My problem is with the accents.

When I read it as UNICODE,
the char `é` is shown as `e` (2 chars : `e` and `'`)

same problem for `è` 
which is seen as `` e` `` (2 chars : `e` and `` ` ``)

Why that ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: More precision please. What are the data types. Show code.

Comment: Yes, more information please.  What version of Delphi are you using?  What are you reading a string from exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is indeed the wrong composition mode, as guessed by Rudy, then [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function may help you convert the string to precomposed mode. See note "WC_COMPOSITECHECK and related flags" at the end of WideCharToMultiByte help.

Comment: That converts to a codepaged AnsiString, with all the risks that come with it. I'd rather use NormalizeString (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: You're right, NormalizeString is a better solution - unless you program has to support Windows XP.

Answer (score 4):

Unicode has two **composition modes**. This is explained [in this ICU document](http://icu-project.org/docs/papers/optimized_unicode_composition_and_decomposition.html). Apparently the string you have been reading uses *decomposition* mode (so `é` is encoded as `e` and `´`). Windows, by default, uses *precomposed* mode, where `é` is encoded as a separate character.

Converting from one mode to the other makes sense if you want to compare strings. There is, however, no uniform way to do this. The ICU document gives some help.

The composition mode should, if done *properly*, not make any difference on the screen.

### Update

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374126%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explains a little more about how to normalize Unicode strings on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

A probable reason for appearance of the separate diacritical marks is data loss in Unicode -> ANSI conversion. Here is a code sample (Delphi 2009):

```
type
  Str1252 = type AnsiString(1252);

var
  S, S2: string;
  S1: Str1252;

begin
  SetLength(S, 2);
  S[1]:= Char($0041);
  S[2]:= Char($0301);
  S1:= S;   // Ord(S1[2]) = $B4; the compiler issues warning W1058:
            // Implicit string cast with potential data loss from 'string' to 'Str1252'
  S2:= S1;  // Ord(S2[2]) = $B4
  ShowMessage(S + ' --> ' + S2);  // Á --> A´
end;
```